# COleException at memory location for COleSafeArray

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to work with the following sample code that was provided to me

```
// select the Access levels from access level list
BSTR myBstr = SysAllocString(L"Hello World");
COleSafeArray saAccessLevels;
VARIANT vAccls;

saAccessLevels.CreateOneDim(VT_BSTR, 1);
saAccessLevels.PutElement(0, myBstr); // <-- Error after this line
vAccls = saAccessLevels.Detach();
```

The Visual C++ debugger breaks at the line noted in the above comment and I get the following errors:

```
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\olemisc.cpp(423) : AppMsg - Warning: constructing COleException, scode = E_INVALIDARG ($80070057).
First-chance exception at 0x75371D4D in MyApplication.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: COleException at memory location 0x0057FC58.
Unhandled exception at 0x75371D4D in MyApplication.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: COleException at memory location 0x0057FC58.
```

I am not familiar with C++ programming.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the PutElement method incorrectly.  The first parameter is a pointer to an array of indices.  Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfe06hkd.aspx).